# Найти проверочное слово для безударной гласной

Tags: орфография

Как проверить в слове "Преподаватель" букву "о"? Разбор по составу на разных сайтах абсолютно различен (непонятно, где корень). Будет ли проверочным словом "пОдати" (если "по" не приставка)?

Comment: Попробуйте образовать страдательное причастие прошедшего времени, совершенного вида.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидная словообразовательная цепочка: **дать  – преподать –преподавать – преподаватель.**

Но  семантически эти глаголы имеют разное значение.

**ПРЕПОДАТЬ,** св. что. Наставляя, советуя, сообщить, изложить. П. первые представления о зарождении жизни. Позвольте п. вам совет. Ему преподали хороший урок (сделано что-л. поучительное, служащее назиданием кому-л.).

**ПРЕПОДАВАТЬ** 1. Обучая кого-нибудь чему-нибудь, **передавать** какие-нибудь сведения, излагать. 2. Заниматься педагогической деятельностью, быть где-нибудь учителем, профессором.

Поэтому морфемный разбор выглядит так: **преподава/ть – преподава/тель.**

Тем не менее очевидно, что ПРЕ и ПО – это **приставки в составе корня преподава-**, а в русском языке нет приставки ПА (кроме пагубный, паводок).

**Проверять эту приставку не надо** (формальной проверки нет), хотя в других словах она встречается в ударной позиции: поступать – поступь, подавать – поданный и др.

Comment: А чем плохо простое "преподан(ный)"?

Comment: Можно и "препОданный", но всё равно формально это проверка глагола "преподать", а не "преподавать".

Comment: Спасибо! ПРЕПОДАННЫЙ, пожалуй, то, что нужно.

Comment: @Alex_ander, кажется, Ваше слово имело успех, Вам тогда нужно оформить ответ. Но вот остается вопрос: это ПРАВИЛЬНАЯ проверка? Для школы, например, подойдет?

Comment: Есть правило, запрещающее проверять глаголы изменением вида, но проблемная категория глаголов имеет в несовершенном виде ударную "а" (не наш случай), напр. опоздать-опаздывать.

Comment: Дело не в этом. Опоздать и опаздывать - это однокоренные глаголы, а преподать и преподавать формально имеют разные корни. Кроме того, здесь вопрос принципиальный: если корень включает в себя связанные приставки, нужно ли их проверять вообще. Если бы не было этого причастия с ударной позицией приставки, мы бы стали считать О непроверяемой корневой гласной?

Comment: "Дать" и "давать" не однокоренные?

Comment: ПО семантике "преподать" и "преподавать" не однокоренные, а "дать" и "давать" однокоренные только между собой. Нужно  быть формалистами до конца или не быть ими. Или вообще не проверять гласную в приставке с одной формой написания, или проверять строго по правилам.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант: ***препóд*** (сниж. от *преподаватель*).

См. [**"Русский орфографический словарь"**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4&all=x):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Жаргон не всегда закономерно образуется (напр. "г**и**мор").

Comment: Интересно, что скажет сам "препод" по поводу такой проверки.